# How to rename multiple columns of a table in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table , say table1 and it has three columns ( **col1_a , col2_b, col3_c**) .  I want to rename the columns to **col1 , col2 , col3** .
But the thing is I want to rename all columns in a single query .

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `select`:

```
select col1_a as col1, col2_a as col2, col3_a as col3
from t;
```

If you want to actually change the names in the table, I think you need three alter tables:

```
alter table t rename column col1_a to col1;
alter table t rename column col2_a to col2;
alter table t rename column col3_a to col3;
```

I don't think Snowflake allows multiple renames with a single `alter table`.

Comment: This is correct, `ALTER TABLE <name> RENAME COLUMN <col_name> TO <new_col_name>` does not accept more than column at a time